# Need 120 A current limiter for 200 A source

Tags: mosfet, high-current

I would like an inexpensive circuit; wider tolerances are acceptable. I have a 200 A automotive alternator from which I anticipate 50-80 A will be called upon from the vehicle accessories over time.

I would like to tap off at up to a 120 A load to charge some lithium batteries. The output would simply be limited to never go over 120 A and 10-20 A drift would be acceptable in most cases. I'd also like a pot in the circuit if possible to fine-tune that maximum, say, for instance, if there was another load on the regular auto that mean perhaps only 100 A was available.

I am guessing that I will need a group of MOSFETs wired in parallel on a good heat sink to accomplish this, but I wonder if there is a simple circuit because I don't see much online regarding these heavier current loads that can be varied using MOSFETs.

I would not be looking at anything fancy like found in a regulated power supply, but simply a few components that guarantee not much more than 120 A is going to be seen as available on the output side of the circuit.

Comment: You do realize that a 200A alternator doesn't always put out 200A, right? In the same way a an engine rated for 500HP doesn't always need to be outputting 500HP and can output anything between 0 and 500HP. Some ratings indicate capability while others indicate performance. The current rating on your alternator is for capability, the voltage rating is for performance.

Comment: Surely such a function would be built into the charger itself.

Comment: If you use a current limiter, and the circuit needs more than 120A, it will drop the voltage of the circuit.

Comment: Also, you don't plan on charging these lithium batteries just by hooking the alternator up to them do you as if it were a lead-acid? Don't do that. You need a charger.

Comment: Let's see. You'll need a way to monitor the battery charging requirements (perhaps as set through a user interface) and then a way to control the vehicle engine RPM so as to ensure the alternator can properly supply the required power during charging. So this is a rather sophisticated closed-loop control system. Luckily, this is only a few horse-power so taking all the inefficiencies into account you might be better off just buying a 6 HP to 8 HP garden utility gas engine with a custom generator for charging and be done with it. Likely less fuel use, too.

Comment: @DKNguyen This part confuses me.  Batteries such as Lion 120aH lifepo4 claim they are drop in replacements but take up to 100a each so how can this work.   I would be using a BMS but as someone pointed out if the BMS ever drops suddenly there will be the "alternator load dump" effect

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple way to do what you are asking.  To do what you want, you need a BMS for the lithium battery that can be told how much power to draw.

I'm assuming that you're using a BMS (Battery Management System) to charge the battery.

1. The BMS has no idea how much power it can draw from the alternator.  If you try to limit the current with a separate circuit, then all that circuit can realistically do is either shut off all power to the BMS, or drop the voltage until the BMS shuts itself off.  There is no way to tell the BMS how much current it can have - unless the BMS specifically has that function.
2. The maximum power available from an alternator depends on the engine speed.  It may be 200A when driving along, but considerebly less when the engine is idling.  If you're not careful, you could be charging the lithium battery at 120A while the alternator is only producing 50A.  The extra 70A would be coming from the vehicle's own battery.  You need to check the output of the alternator at all times, to make sure you aren't running the vehicle's battery flat.

Answer (score 1):

The expensive part of monitoring triple-digit amps is the sensor.  Two options are a big-assed shunt resistor, and a Hall effect sensor.  The hall sensor delivers a much larger volts-per-amp signal with zero power dissipation in the main power path, but is $$$.

After the sensor, the signal can be manipulated (gain and offset) with an opamp, driving a power transistor that regulates the alternator through the field winding as already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

There are current limiting DC/DC chargers already present on the market, commercialized, for this precise user-case; charging lithium from an alternator source without igniting everything.

The only 120A rated units I am aware of on the market would be the Sterling BB12120.

Please do not consider the method currently popular on narrowboats and low-cost campervans of just having long, thin cable as a resistor. It's insane and it'll probably be the first time you ever hear an insurance company actually laugh at you if you ever try to make a claim for the 20 meters of burning cable (and vehicle) onboard.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a dedicated motor to drive the alternator, which I presume you have some sort of speed control over it.

A good alternator may provide 50% of rated current at an idle of 800 RPM and 100% at 1500 RPM or more. So you simply limit the current by the motor speed and an ammeter for measuring current.

e.g.
200 AMP Alternator for Nissan Sentra, 2002 - 2006 1.8L L4

Idle Output:    100+ AMPS
Full Output:    200+ AMPS @ 1200 Engine RPM !

There are also field current limiting methods but this may be simpler.

Comment: Thanks but it's on a RV engine so that won't be an option.   I do thank you, however.

Comment: Alternators are like transistors as their current gain amplifiers field current in current source out to the battery so by limiting the  field current , You can limit the charge current.

Answer (score 0):

Alternators are current sources, attempting to gate a large portion of the output current will get messy very quickly. (it's called a load dump)

Take the accessory load into account when regulating the alternator current, or use
a second alternator to charge the lithium batteries using the field winding of the alternator to regulate the current draw.

Comment: Thank you!   Maybe I will experiment with a wire wound resistor with some 12 gauge wire to see if I can limit the load that way.   It still sounds like if the BMS cuts off abruptly, the "load dump" will still be an issue even if I am using a resistor such as this.   Lithium adds so many quirks I am beginning to wonder if it is even worth it and instead just add 2 additional wet cell GC2 to my camper for a total of 4 instead of investing a life savings in all the lithium safety stuff.  $300 for new alt, $400 for B2B, plus actual lithium cost.   Too much I think..

Comment: Another curiosity, since the lead/acid starting battery will also be across the line from the alternator, I wonder how much of a voltage spike "sink" that would take care of in the case of a "load dump"?

Comment: Two different batteries with different chemistries in parrallell will not work well... potentially real bad: "dreamliner" or worse.

Comment: Only connected when engine is running so this also means that they both have a high amperage 14.2V source across them during the time they are attached to the alternator, so they are likely not responding to the other bank as long as the 14.2V level stays stable.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the alternator output by PWMing the control winding. This is the windings on the rotor. It is normally connected to the control circuit with slip rings and by controlling this you control the output of the field windings which are rectified by the normally built in diodes. This was done on a production basis by one then several of the automotive manufacturers where the regulator was replaced with the engine control module then other modules over time by different OEMs. This controls the voltage by controlling the current into the battery and its internal resistance. No need to control the driver RPM with this method.

This will allow you to control current as you asked and was originally used to control Lead Acid batteries. It is not safe, actually very dangerous to do this with lithium batteries without the additional control systems in place.